# How do I ask for clarification on an existing answer if I am very new?

Tags: support

My PC became very slow while booting and I wanted to know why? I google and find this interesting answer

[How to diagnose slow booting or logon in Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/250267/how-to-diagnose-slow-booting-or-logon-in-windows-7)

but somehow the link provided in the answer is dead and I wanted to ask if the answerer could provide a new link

But since I do not have 50 rep I could not post a comment, so I decided post a question on meta, but meta says you need to have at least 5 rep on the SU site in order to post a question here.

So my question is how do I get the answer as a new person to the site?

below are few concerns on the same

> If I ask a new question on slow booting in win7, it would probably (surely) be marked as a duplicate for the above mentioned question.
>
> The question you are reading might be closed because it might be considered off-topic

so what can a person do in this scenario? do post some other dummy questions or answer any existing questions which he might not be capable of?

above option might let him gain enough reputation to perform the necessary action, but at the same time it will require too much time for him to get his answer which might surely defeat the purpose of the site.

Comment: Which link is broken exactly?

Comment: @Ramhound link to  Windows Performance Analysis Tools in [Tomwij's answer](http://superuser.com/a/250273/4377) is broken

Comment: @Sathya - Fixed the link. Of course I had no problem finding the working linked on Microsoft's website. )

Comment: @Ramhound thanks for fixing :)

Comment: @Sathya - I believe I have the correct version.  ADK has been updated since the question was asked.  I believe the current version can be used, it will generate Windows RE 5.1/5.0 images, but links pointing to the previous version were redirected to the current version.  Windows 7 is listed as being supported so I went ahead and updated the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But since I do not have 50 rep I could not post a comment, so I decided post a question on meta, but meta says you need to have at least 5 rep on the SU site in order to post a question here.

5 rep is.. easy to get. Take a look at existing answers.See any problems, fix them by suggesting an edit. Approved suggested edits gives you 2 rep. Answering questions gives you chance to get upvotes - and each upvote gets you 10 rep. If you answer & your answer is accepted, you get 15 rep.

> so what can a person do in this scenario? do post some other dummy questions or answer any existing questions which he might not be capable of?

No, answer questions which you know about.

> but at the same time it will require too much time for him to get his answer which might surely defeat the purpose of the site.

I really don't think it's that difficult to get rep. Just "maintenance" (edits etc) should net you enough

Comment: That make sense, at this moment I can think of the mentioned possibilities. It is not actually difficult to get rep and get the desired answer. Now I can realize that I was already frustrated by the issue I had and SU doubled it up by restricting me based on the rep thus hindering my abilities to think calmly. Anyways Thank you for the informative answer.